# Ruby + JSON + Regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, json

I'm working on a RoR project and I am passing a JSON object to a script.  Specifically, a list of events to a jquery calendar.

First I get the necessary events from active record and convert them to json:

```
@events = CalendarEvent.find(:all, :conditions => ["mentor_id = ?", current_user]).to_json(:only => [:id, :availability, :starts_at, :ends_at])
```

This returns the following:

```
[{"calendar_event":{"starts_at":"2010-08-14T17:15:00Z","id":1,"availability":true,"ends_at":"2010-08-14T17:45:00Z"}},
 {"calendar_event":{"starts_at":"2010-08-15T15:45:00Z","id":2,"availability":true,"ends_at":"2010-08-15T16:15:00Z"}},
 ...]
```

However, I am running into problems because the script is expecting the following format:

```
[{"starts_at":"2010-08-14T17:15:00Z","id":1,"availability":true,"ends_at":"2010-08-14T17:45:00Z"},
 {"starts_at":"2010-08-15T15:45:00Z","id":2,"availability":true,"ends_at":"2010-08-15T16:15:00Z"},
 ...]
```

At first I thought it would be a simple matter of popping the values from the separate hashes, and returning an array filled with those.  However, it seems that everything in the array is one big string.  So I was trying to get the necessary stuff using a regular expression.  My best shot was:

```
@json = @events.scan(/\[\{\"calendar_event\":(\{.*\})\}\]*/)
```

But this returns something of the form:

```
[["{\"starts_at\":\"2010-08-14T17:15:00Z\",\"id\":1,\"availability\":true,\"ends_at\":\"2010-08-14T17:45:00Z\"}},{\"calendar_event\":{\"starts_at\":\"2010-08-15T15:45:00Z\",\"id\":2,\"availability\":true,\"ends_at\":\"2010-08-15T16:15:00Z\"}},..."]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

Have fun.

[Reading documentation helps.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

Comment: Thank you. I wish I had found this a few hours ago.

Comment: classic example of RTFM that made me laugh; good advice and great answer !